# Send data from Visual C++ via socket on the same machine

Tags: sockets, visual-c++

I am currently in a project involving data visualization of a signal captured from a device which has a Visual C++ API. I currently can log each datasample to file, but I'd like to do some sort of plot to screen.

I have had a previous successful experience with a similar job using socket between C++ and Python, but the code was lost. I have the Python socket "receiver" to reuse, but don't have the Visual C++ "sender" to reverse engineer or otherwise copy/paste.

My current Python code, which was working very fine, is:

```
import SocketServer

class SocketHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()

        ## do something with 'data' here!

server = SocketServer.UDPServer(("192.168.1.23", 8888), SocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

And the part of the Visual C++ that currently logs to file and I want to send to the socket is:

```
#include <fstream>

//(...lots of code...)

short int * dataBuff;
unsigned int dataNum;
int isAcqRunning;
int startFromTrg, stopFromTrg;
unsigned int firstSample, lastSample;
int errcode;
int i;

std::ofstream out("./out.txt");


// device->transferData is called inside a loop
// to get data from aquisition hardware's buffer
errcode = device->transferData(&dataBuff, &dataNum, &isAcqRunning,
                              &startFromTrg, &stopFromTrg,
                              &firstSample, &lastSample);
if(errcode == 0)
{

    printf("\n Acquired samples: %d", dataNum);

    for (i=firstSample; i<lastSample; i++)
        out<<dataBuff[i]<<'\n';  /////// I'd like to send dataBuff[i] via socket!!
}

//(...lots of more code...)
```

Possibly useful additional information:

- I'm using VisualStudio 2010 in Windows7;
- This is the first time I touch C++ code in my life, I use Python almost exclusively;
- I haven't have success trying to follow C++ examples from books and sites because, as it appears, C++ and VISUAL C++ are NOT the same thing and can behave very differently :o(

I thank very much for any help, and for reading this.

(EDIT: if there is a better way to do that without any additional complexity overhead for a noob, I would be glad to try. I like the socket stuff because it is language-transparent and solved a previous problem with very good speed)